# Read complex numbers from a single column in gnuplot

Tags: split, gnuplot, complex-numbers

I'd like to plot data which is stored on a file in three columns like this :

```
316   0.662500024   180.382+137.860i
317   0.664285719   188.515+135.229i
318   0.666071415   196.834+131.997i
319   0.667857111   205.536+127.380i
320   0.669642866   213.829+122.105i
321   0.671428561   222.220+116.453i
```

The first column contains the sample's number, so it's not really interesting for me. The second column contains a frequency, and the third column contains a complex impedance measured with a VNA.
What I would like to do is split the real and complex parts to plot them separately, or plot the complex number magnitude.

I tried something like this, according from what I read online :
`plot 'datafile.data' using (1000*$2):(sqrt($3**2+$4**2)) '%lf  %lf%lfi'`*
But it doesnt work, which is not surprising since I did this in the blind...

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your command to

```
plot 'datafile.dat' using (1000*$2):(sqrt($3**2+$4**2)) '%lf %lf %lf%lfi'
```

You are missing one number that occurs in your file.  Even though you are not using the first number, you *must* tell gnuplot about it.

Comment: @MaximGi, Glad to help.  If an answer is helpful to you, please consider accepting it.  This will award the answerer and yourself with a small amount of reputation, and mark the question as answered.